# How to define induction on natural numbers in Scala 2.13?

Tags: scala, implicit, dependent-type, scala-2.13, peano-numbers

Consider the following definition of natural numbers.

```scala
sealed trait Nat

final case object Z extends Nat

final case class S[N <: Nat]() extends Nat
```

And the following definition of vectors.

```scala
sealed trait Vec[N <: Nat, +A]

final case object Nil extends Vec[Z.type, Nothing]

final case class Cons[N <: Nat, +A](head: A, tail: Vec[N, A]) extends Vec[S[N], A]
```

Now, I defined the induction on natural numbers as follows.

```scala
trait Alg[P[_ <: Nat]] {
  val z: P[Z.type]

  def s[N <: Nat](p: P[N]): P[S[N]]
}

def ind[N <: Nat, P[_ <: Nat]](alg: Alg[P])(implicit indN: Alg[P] => P[N]) = indN(alg)

implicit def indZ[P[_ <: Nat]](): Alg[P] => P[Z.type] = alg => alg.z

implicit def indS[N <: Nat, P[_ <: Nat]](implicit indN: Alg[P] => P[N]): Alg[P] => P[S[N]] = alg => alg.s(indN(alg))
```

And, I want to use it to define a function that creates a fixed size vector.

```scala
def rep[N <: Nat, A](head: A) = {
  type P[N <: Nat] = Vec[N, A]

  val alg = new Alg[P] {
    val z: P[Z.type] = Nil

    def s[N <: Nat](tail: P[N]): P[S[N]] = Cons(head, tail)
  }

  ind[N, P](alg) // No implicit view available from Alg[P] => P[N]
}

val vec = rep[S[S[S[Z.type]]], Int](37) // expected Cons(37, Cons(37, Cons(37, Nil)))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Scala doesn't know which implicit value to use. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't put `()` in `implicit def indZ[P[_ <: Nat]]()`. The implicits `implicit def indZ[P[_ <: Nat]]()` and `implicit def indZ[P[_ <: Nat]]` are very different

[How to write an implicit Numeric for a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75458954/how-to-write-an-implicit-numeric-for-a-tuple)

It's convenient to introduce `type Z = Z.type`. Then you can write just `Z` instead of `Z.type`.

Scala is not an actual theorem prover. Implicits are not resolved like that. If you defined `implicit def indZ` and `implicit def indS`, Scala knows implicits (and their types) `indZ`, `indS(indZ)`, `indS(indS(indZ))`, ... but it can't generate an implicit of an unknown length `indS(...(indS(indZ)))`. So with inductive logic based on implicits you can prove theorems for a fixed `N` (like `Z`, `S[Z]`, `S[S[Z]]`, ...) but not for arbitrary `N` (or for arbitrary `N` but with implicits of a fixed length). At those places where you have arbitrary `N` you should add an evidence (implicit parameter) `Alg[P] => P[N]`, it will be checked later for a concrete `N`. So to say, if a method lacks an implicit (see your compile error `No implicit view available from Alg[P] => P[N]`) then you just add it as an implicit parameter:

[Scala: Question about shapeless to tranform HList to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308836/scala-question-about-shapeless-to-tranform-hlist-to-list)

[Implicit Encoder for TypedDataset and Type Bounds in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55637342/implicit-encoder-for-typeddataset-and-type-bounds-in-scala)

[How to resolve implicit lookup by bounded generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495884/how-to-resolve-implicit-lookup-by-bounded-generic)

[Typeclasses methods called in functions with type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57675918/typeclasses-methods-called-in-functions-with-type-parameters)

[Play-JSON cannot find implicit Writes[T] for type parameter T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032001/jsonplay-cannot-find-implicit-writest-for-type-parameter-t)

[Why the Scala compiler can provide implicit outside of object, but cannot inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437826/why-the-scala-compiler-can-provide-implicit-outside-of-object-but-cannot-inside)

So try

```
class Rep[A](head: A) {
  type P[N <: Nat] = Vec[N, A]

  val alg = new Alg[P] {
    val z: P[Z] = Nil
    def s[N <: Nat](tail: P[N]): P[S[N]] = Cons(head, tail)
  }

  def apply[N <: Nat](implicit ev: Alg[P] => P[N]): P[N] = ind[N, P](alg)
  //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ added
}

val vec = new Rep[Int](37)[S[S[S[Z]]]] // Cons(37, Cons(37, Cons(37, Nil)))
```

Be careful with building your logic on implicits of functional type `Alg[P] => P[N]`. Functional types play special role for implicits, they are for implicit conversions and such implicits are resolved slightly differently than implicits of all other types:

[Implicit view not working - is my implicit def to blame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63964610/implicit-view-not-working-is-my-implicit-def-to-blame)

[In scala, are there any condition where implicit view won't be able to propagate to other implicit function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630439/in-scala-are-there-any-condition-where-implicit-view-wont-be-able-to-propagate)

[When calling a scala function with compile-time macro, how to failover smoothly when it causes compilation errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205940/when-calling-a-scala-function-with-compile-time-macro-how-to-failover-smoothly)

[Scala Kleisli throws an error in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751493/scala-kleisli-throws-an-error-in-intellij)

[What are the hidden rules regarding the type inference in resolution of implicit conversions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002466/what-are-the-hidden-rules-regarding-the-type-inference-in-resolution-of-implicit)

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/can-we-wean-scala-off-implicit-conversions/4388

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposed-changes-and-restrictions-for-implicit-conversions/4923

This is improved in Scala 3: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/conversions.html (a new type class `Conversion` is introduced instead of standard functional type, although currently with more restrictions than in Scala 2, for example implicit conversions into a path-dependent type are currently impossible - *But https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/7412 https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/8523*).

It can be better to introduce a new type class `TC[P[_ <: N], N <: Nat]` and build your inductive logic on `TC[P, N]` rather than standard functional types `Alg[P] => P[N]`.

It's important to know how to debug implicits (at compile time)

[In scala 2 or 3, is it possible to debug implicit resolution process in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348301/in-scala-2-or-3-is-it-possible-to-debug-implicit-resolution-process-in-runtime)