# Why this typecheck fails? (scala.compiletime.ops.int)

Tags: scala, compile-time, typechecking, scala-3

I was making a own fixed-size vector class and this code was rejected

```scala
import scala.compiletime.ops.int._

enum Tensor1[Dim <: Int, +T]:
  case Empty extends Tensor1[0, Nothing]
  case Cons[N <: Int, A](head: A, tail: Tensor1[N, A]) extends Tensor1[S[N], A]

  def ::[SuperT >: T](operand: SuperT): Tensor1[Dim + 1, SuperT] = Cons(operand, this)
```

with this message:

```
[error] Tree: Tensor1.Cons.apply[Dim, SuperT](operand, this)
[error] I tried to show that
[error]   Tensor1.Cons[Dim, SuperT]
[error] conforms to
[error]   Tensor1[Dim + (1 : Int), SuperT]
[error] but the comparison trace ended with `false`:
```

but when I changed `Dim + 1` to `S[Dim]` in definition of `::`, it works.

```scala
  def ::[SuperT >: T](operand: SuperT): Tensor1[S[Dim], SuperT] = Cons(operand, this)
```

Why this happens? Are `S` and `+ 1` different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `S` and `+ 1` are indeed different.

```scala
type S[N <: Int] <: Int

type +[X <: Int, Y <: Int] <: Int
```

They are implemented in compiler internals.

Scala is not an actual theorem prover.
It allows you to prove theorems but doesn't prove theorems for you.
Scala knows that `10 + 1` or `1 + 10` are `S[10]` but doesn't know that `n + 1` or `1 + n` are `S[n]`

```scala
summon[10 + 1 =:= S[10]] //compiles
summon[1 + 10 =:= S[10]] //compiles

type n <: Int
//summon[n + 1 =:= S[n]] // doesn't compile
//summon[1 + n =:= S[n]] // doesn't compile
```

Even when `S` and `+` are implemented inductively

```scala
sealed trait Nat
class S[N <: Nat] extends Nat
object _0 extends Nat
type _0 = _0.type
type _1 = S[_0]

type +[N <: Nat, M <: Nat] = N match
  case _0 => M
  case S[n] => S[n + M]
```

it's obvious that `_1 + n =:= S[n]` but not obvious that `n + _1 =:= S[n]` (this is a theorem to be proved)

```scala
type n <: Nat
summon[_1 + n =:= S[n]] // compiles
//summon[n + _1 =:= S[n]] // doesn't compile
```

If you define addition inductively with respect to the 2nd argument

```scala
type +[N <: Nat, M <: Nat] = M match
  case _0 => N
  case S[m] => S[N + m]
```

then vice versa `n + _1 =:= S[n]` becomes obvious but `_1 + n =:= S[n]` has to be proved

```scala
//summon[_1 + n =:= S[n]] // doesn't compile
summon[n + _1 =:= S[n]] // compiles
```

[How to define induction on natural numbers in Scala 2.13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742747/how-to-define-induction-on-natural-numbers-in-scala-2-13)